# Issue reading video in stagewebview (Adobe AIR for Android)

Tags: android, air, html5-video, stagewebview

I have a problem reading video in a StageWebView for Android device.

I use the html5 video tag and I would like to read this video in a StageWebView for an Android application.

For iOS I had no problem but on Android device the player is black and I hear only sounds.

I tried a lot of JS players but all have the same issue.

Has anyone had this kind of issue?

Comment: Are you sure you are using a supported video format for android? See http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html for list of supported media formats.

Comment: Yes i'm sure i use MPEG-4 (.mp4). When i put the video in fullscreen i have images and sounds but not in normal size...

Comment: I have the same issue and have tried heaps of different formats, straight <video> tags, 3rd party JS/CSS video players, and anything else I can think of.  I have come to believe that its an AIR bug on Android and that StageWebView simply doesn't display video unless it is in full-screen mode.

Answer (score 5):

In `App.xml` Android manifest, try enable hardware acceleration. Maybe it's that..

```
<android>
        <manifestAdditions><![CDATA[
...
            <manifest android:installLocation="auto">
...
                <application android:enabled="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
```